# Can we obtain the identity, constant, and fixpoint datatype constructors for arbitrary type-producing kinds?

Tags: haskell

Here are some type constructors:

```
type T0 = Type

type I0 :: T0 -> T0
data I0 x = I0 { getI0 :: x }

type K0 :: T0 -> (T0 -> T0)
data K0 x y = K0 { getK0 :: x }

type Mu0 :: (T0 -> T0) -> T0
data Mu0 f = Mu0 { unMu0 :: f (Mu0 f) }
```

Here are some more type constructors:

```
type T1 = Type -> Type

type I1 :: T1 -> T1
data I1 f x = I1 { getI1 :: f x }

type K1 :: T1 -> (T1 -> T1)
data K1 f g x = K1 { getK1 :: f x }

type Mu1 :: (T1 -> T1) -> T1
data Mu1 ff x = Mu1 { unMu1 :: ff (Mu1 ff) x }
```

We can organize these type constructors into a data family:

```
class Context (k :: Type)
  where
  data I :: k -> k
  data K :: k -> (k -> k)
  data Mu :: (k -> k) -> k

instance Context Type
  where
  data I x = I0 { getI0 :: x }
  data K x y = K0 { getK0 :: x }
  data Mu f = Mu0 { getMu0 :: f (Mu0 f) }

instance Context (Type -> Type)
  where
  data I f x = I1 { getI1 :: f x }
  data K f g x = K1 { getK1 :: f x }
  data Mu ff x = Mu1 { unMu1 :: ff (Mu1 ff) x }

instance Context (Type -> Type -> Type)
  ...

instance Context ((Type -> Type) -> Type)
  ...
```

These definitions are an example of ad-hoc polymorphism, in that I must laboriously instantiate the class on a case by case basis for each `Type`-producing kind I can think of. Is it possible to define these datatype constructors in a *parametrically* polymorphic way, so that we have datatype constructors of kind:

```
type I :: forall k. k -> k
type K :: forall k. k -> (k -> k)
type Mu :: forall k. (k -> k) -> k
```

which I can instantiate at any `Type` producing kind without further ceremony (e.g. instantiating a class for said kind)?

Comment: Have you tried writing `instance (Context k, Context k') => Context (k -> k')`? If it was possible, would that be enough for you?

Comment: @DanielWagner I have been trying to write it inductively, but haven't managed to do it. If it can be implemented that way it would be enough for me.

Comment: Although what I was trying to do was `Context r => Context (k -> r)`, I didn't think to demand `Context k`.

Comment: Well, you can generalize your `Type -> Type` instance to `k -> Type` without even changing its body. If you're willing to uncurry everything that seems like it gets you everywhere you can get. But I think you've hamstrung yourself a bit by demanding that it be a data family -- those must always produce `Type` at the very end, so I don't think you can get anywhere that the `k -> Type` instance doesn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

How about a CPS sort of encoding?

`A -> B` to `(A -> Type) -> (B -> Type)`

So at kind level we want

```
 I : (a -> Type) -> (a -> Type)
 K : a -> b -> (a -> Type) -> Type
 Fix : ((a -> Type) -> (a -> Type)) ->  (a -> Type) -> Type
```

I is easy being just

```
 newtype I x k = I (k x)
```

K is slightly harder

```
 newtype K a b k = K (k a)
```

I think fix is

```
  newtype Fix f k = Fix (k (f (Fix f))
```

But I'm not quite sure.